# Can not login to Normal mode

Tags: installation

I installed ubuntu 12 in my old PC Acer Power Series. After installation i got the Login Screen which appears unusally big. when i logged-in in some fail-safe mode. I got the normal ubuntu running. but if i restart the system i can login using fail-safe mode but i can't login normally.

I think the problem must be i don't have a graphic card. Even if i do have one that must be very very low configuration one. Kindly help me with graphic card config if that is the problem with my PC.

I just want to use ubuntu for normal documentation purpose.

I am new to ubuntu so techcies help me with basic guidance.

Thank you.
Karthik Muralitharan

Answer (score 0):

The easiest wil be to find Additional Drivers application amd hope that Ubuntu picked up your video card's native driver. Install it if it's there.

Comment: What should i install and where do i find and how do i install.

Comment: Can you see any menus when you log onto your system?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login in the fail-save mode
2. Go to the terminal en type: sudo nautilus (the pogram will ask your password)
3. go to file system: "etc/default/grub an open that file (click on it)
4. Search for the text GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and change it to
5. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
6. Save the file
7. Close nautilus
8. You are back in the terminal.  Type: sudo update-grub
9. Close the terminal and reboot the computer
10. Try this time the mormal mode to boot.

Comment: I tried the above solution and i got into normal booting but i get unusually big view of screen. I don't know what is the problem. My PC is Acer Power Series Desktop with low config (512MB).

Comment: OK, there are different ways for the solution.  First thing to do going to the update screen of your system, and verify if it is not mentioned that you must install specific drivers. If yes do so.  Second thing is to verify (via the dash) : screen (resolution). Can you change it to the normal resolution? If yes, do so